# Geolocator is Fetching location So fast that causing my app getting slower while I just want user's current location for once only in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I m trying to fetch user's current location for once in my flutter app, Geolocation API or location API are continuously fetching location while I m just fetch current location that causing my app slower. How can I resolve this problem so that it fetches the User's location for once only?

```
    Geolocator().getCurrentPosition().then((currentLocation) {
      Geolocator()
          .placemarkFromCoordinates(
              currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude)
          .then((placemark) => {
                setState(() {
                  location =
                      "${placemark[0].locality}, ${placemark[0].administrativeArea}";
                })
              });
    });
```

I have also used location dependency and still geting the same problem

Comment: Please post your whole code. I suspect that your call to `setState` triggers your whole geolocation logic again. And again. And again. You need to have a way to stop this cycle.

Comment: Also, consider using `async`/`await` and a `FutureBuilder`, instead of duct-taping your solution with `.then()` chains. It's not 90s Javascript anymore, this is the future :)

Comment: yeah thanks, it was setState and I was calling this method at the wrong place, and I ll sure look after your suggestion

Comment: @nvoigt, wow, ain't that a futuristic pun